# Routing issues with Laravel 4 on shared hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

I have just launched a Laravel 4 powered website on a GoDaddy shared hosting and I have a problem - on a successful login, the website tries to redirect me to the correct page and after the message changes, it redirects me back to the main page.

It shows me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mLHs.jpg), and after a second it changes to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj4YB.jpg) and brings me back to the main page.

You can try this for yourself by visiting [the website](http://citmthegame.ezquisite.com/public/) and logging in with `serban` as the username and `start1` as the password.

Routes :

```
Route::post('/account/sign-in', array(
    'as' => 'account-sign-in-post',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@postSignIn'
    ));

Route::get('/account/sign-in', array(
    'as' => 'account-sign-in',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@getSignIn'
    ));

Route::get('/account/create-char', array(
    'as' => 'create-character',
    'uses' => 'AccountController@getCharCreate'
    ));
```

Controller `AccountController` :

```
   public function getCharCreate() {
    return View::make('account.createchar');
}

public function postSignIn() {
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'username'      => 'required',
            'password'  => 'required'
            )
        );

    if($validator->fails()) {
                //Redirect to sign in page
        return Redirect::route('home')
        ->withErrors($validator)
        ->withInput();
    } else {
                //Attempt user sign in
        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;
        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('password'),
            'active' => 1
            ), $remember);  


        if($auth) {
                    //Redirect to intended page

            Session::put('theuser', Input::get('username'));



            $resultchar = DB::table('users')
            ->join('characters', function($join)
            {
                $join->on('users.id', '=', 'characters.user_id')
                ->where('users.username', '=', Session::get('theuser'));
            })
            ->get();

            if($resultchar == false) {
                return Redirect::route('create-character');

            } else {

                $selected_char = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->character()->whereRaw('lord_id = id')->first()->char_name;                                                   
                return Redirect::route('char-profile-get', array(Auth::user()->username))
                ->with('selected_char',$selected_char);


            }
        }
        else {



            return Redirect::route('home')
            ->with('global', 'Email/password wrong, or account not activated');


        }
    }

    return Redirect::route('home')
    ->with('global', 'There is a problem signing you in');
}
```

So if the user never created a character it should do this

```
return Redirect::route('create-character');
```

The code arrives at this line, but instead of redirecting me to `/public/account/create-char` it redirects me to the main page `/public/`.

The .htaccess file looks like this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

The communication with the DB works since the server identifies which account is new and which is old. When using an old account, it tries to redirect me to another route, but ends up in the main page. Registration also works, the user is added into the DB's users table before getting redirected back.

Let me know if I should add any more details or code.

Comment: As it stands for me right now, this is clearly a routing problem. On a local server using WAMP Server, everything works like a charm.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I use Laravel 4

Comment: .htaccess is located in public/

Comment: Please edit your post and add the function for `getCharCreate`.

Comment: check to ensure that you have set permissions for the storage folder